# Without submit button validate form elements in Magento

Tags: forms, validation, magento

To add multiple steps before submit form. like:

Registration page:

- Step 1 - Enter first, last name and email (validate on click of next button and show next step)
- Step 2 - Enter Password and Confirm password and submit

Step 1 and step 2 are separate DIV's (Show/hide on Next Click)

Answer (score 6):

You can give a try of this JS snippet:

```
var formToValidate = $('place the id of the form, that I want to validate');
var validator = new Validation(formToValidate);
if(validator.validate()) {
    /* The logic, that you want to execute if you pass the validation. */
    ......
    ......
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Now, i used "NEXT" on first step as sumbit button.
 var formToValidat = $('#formid, #fieldid');
 var validator = new Validation(formToValidat);
 if(validator.validate()) {
     alert("valid")
 }
NOT WORKING

Comment: I think, that you have to use it in the following way: var formToValidat = $('formid'); Also if you have installed firebug or google chrome dev tools, check the console for java scrip errors. Basically new Validation() accept only  FORM element as parameter.

Comment: Not Working - On image/input type="button" click function validate field any other way to do it?

Comment: You need to use validator.validate() in the click handler of the button. Btw what is your level of understanding java script?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes i understand the javascript but i didnt worked with the protoype.js. I know and worked with Core javascript and jquery

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3945931/1016533 It describes how you can handle click events with prototype js. Also, why don't you paste the whole form html in your question?

Comment: new Validation() is the exact class I was looking for to validate my form without actually triggering the submit event. Thank you.